# How can an image be retrieved from an excel worksheet using python xlrd

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

I am using the xlrd python excel library [python-excel](http://www.python-excel.org/). I can read my excel workbook allright (I must say their tutorials are pretty good). BUT I can't retrieve an image stored in a worksheet and thats killing me.

ANY Python method on retrieving an image from a worksheet would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't think xlrd is able to do so. You can embed an image with xlwt, but can't retrieve objects like charts, images and so on in xlrd...

You will have to confirm on the [python-excel list](https://groups.google.com/group/python-excel?lnk=li&hl=en), ask there.